# Can't knit Rmd when using googlesheets4

Tags: r, authentication, google-authentication, googlesheets4

I am attempting to knit a .Rmd file that uses googlesheets4, but the execution fails every time. Here's my code where it fails:

```
for (package in c('tidyverse', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4')) {
  if (!require(package, character.only=T, quietly=T)) {
    install.packages(package)
    library(package, character.only=T)
  }
}
data <- read_sheet("mysheetidgoeshere")
```

When trying to knit the Rmd with this code, it fails on this section and gives this error:

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
Execution halted
```

The thing is, this code works perfectly when ran normally but only fails when trying to knit. I've tried authenticating the session multiple ways but none seem to work.

Using R version 3.5.1, Mac OS X 10.13.6

**Edit**

I was able to knit the Rmd using

```
rmarkdown::render("nameoffile.Rmd")
```

Not sure why the "Knit" button in the Rmarkdown didn't work, but at least the file is knit now.

Comment: Knitting an Rmd doc is not an interactive R session. So, maybe try calling `gs4_auth()` directly?

Comment: I've tried that, but still no luck